# I need to move Data from Cell A2 Sheet 1 to next available Cell A Sheet 2 if a date is input into Cell J2

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement, google-sheets, copy

I need to move Data from Cell A2 OpenWO to next available Cell A Permitting if a date is input into Cell J2 of OpenWO. I used the following if statement.

```
=IF(isdate(OpenWO!J2),OpenWO!A:A,)
```

The problem is that if there is data in Permitting A2 then data does not transfer. So I need to modify statement to go to the next available Cell A

Comment: Please provide an example sheet, where it is shown what the result should be. Or a screenshot at least

Comment: What is in `sheet2!A2`? How does it get there? There might be a formula to get both existing data and that from sheet 1 to that column.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Share a copy of your sheet, no sensitive information.

Comment: You should be aware that sharing your spreadsheet will unavoidably expose your email address.